# Trigger a welcome screen for 2-3 secs after logging in

Tags: java, android

I have created a `Login Screen` and connected my `API` with it and the authentication of emails and passwords work perfectly. What I am trying to do now is : 
1) After the user taps on login and it is successful, A screen is displayed which says WELCOME and closes in 2-3 secs and the the user is back at the home screen again. 
2) If the user launches the application again, that time the welcome screen does not appear. It only comes whenever you login, be it the first time or if you are an existing user, but only when the login button is pressed.
I am new to to `android` so I am going step by step. So I created the home screens. Consumed API's and this is what I am trying now.

Can someone help me solve it? 
I am using `Retrofit` Library.

LOGIN ACTIVITY

```java
public class LoginScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        findViewById(R.id.loginBtnLogin).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.btn_createAccount).setOnClickListener(this);
        private void userLogin(){
        String Loginemail = loginEmail.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        String Loginpassword = loginPassword.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        Call<LoginResponse> call = RetrofitClient
                .getInstance().getApi().userLogin(Loginemail, Loginpassword);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
                LoginResponse loginResponse = response.body();
                if (loginResponse.getObj() != null){
                    Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this, "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intentLogin = new Intent(LoginScreen.this, HomeScreen.class);
                    startActivity(intentLogin);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this, "Please Enter A Valid Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.loginBtnLogin:
                userLogin();
                break;
            case R.id.btn_createAccount:
                 Intent intentRegister = new Intent(LoginScreen.this, CreateAccount.class);
                 startActivity(intentRegister);
                 break;
        }

    }
}
```

RETROFIT CLIENT

```java
public class RetrofitClient {
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://example.com/api/";
    private static RetrofitClient mInstance;
    private Retrofit retrofit;

    private RetrofitClient() {

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    public static synchronized RetrofitClient getInstance() {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new RetrofitClient();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public LoginInterface getApi() {
        return retrofit.create(LoginInterface.class);
    }
}
```

InterfaceApi is perfectly correct and the login response files too (made them with converting pojo from json plugin in android studio)

Comment: If the solution code is long just let me know what is the procedure for it, I search about it and try to work on my own. I don't know what is the way to do it.

Comment: What's the problem of putting the logic of showing welcome screen after you click login? If the user is already logged in, your code will not show welcome screen because you won't go through login screen again to click login.

Comment: Also, if you're looking for data persistence (to check if logged in or not even when the user exists the app), you can read about [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences)

Comment: I know that there is no logic in what I am asking, I am just experimenting things as much I can. I am new to android and learning on my own, so just trying to experiment everything so that I get a good hold of the topics I am covering day by day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'on login button click putt a check if user loggedin successfully start a splash screen for 2-3 seconds and then from splash screen move to home screen'

```
  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                    startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, 
                    yourHomeActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
            }
        },3000);
```

'this code will show welcome screen for three seconds and after that it will move to home screen'

'hop eyou get the solution'

Answer (score 0):

Use shared preference manager to fix this error while login click the stored and check opening the application

```
  public static void isLogin( Context context){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("mypref",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor preferenceEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    preferenceEditor.putBoolean("isLogin",true);
    preferenceEditor.commit();
}
public static void isLogout( Context context){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("mypref",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor preferenceEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    preferenceEditor.putBoolean("isLogin",false);
    preferenceEditor.commit();
}
```

Check here

```
  public static boolean userLoginCheck(Context context){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("mypref",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Boolean isLogin = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isLogin",false);
    return  isLogin;

}
```